# Learn the base of security and defend myself from external attack

Tags: linux, networking, security, osx, windows

i would like to learn and work on internet security, because thia is a world that is in continuos change and id like to improve myself on it..anyone can help me linking site or PDF where i can study this fantastic world?

Comment: Unfortunately stackexchange is not a good place for questions which have opinionated answers. A question here should have a single correct answer. https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: sorry, i don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could follow and Watch CEH Channel on Youtube
2. Install Kali Linux/BackTrack/BlackBuntu and get started with basic tools installed in these operating systems
3. [This document](https://basicinternetsecurity.org/book/basic-internet-security.pdf) could be of some use.